# Importing comma separated data into Excel

Tags: excel, text, get, quotes

1,1,"Pound","The foe is physically pounded with a long tail or a foreleg, etc.",0,40,0,100,35,0,0,0,115,0

2,2,"Karate Chop","The foe is attacked with a sharp chop. It has a high critical-hit ratio.",43,50,1,100,25,0,0,0,115,0

3,3,"DoubleSlap","The foe is slapped repeatedly, back and forth, two to five times in a row.",29,15,0,85,10,0,0,0,115,0

I have a large set of data in the format above. I paste it into Excel and each row takes up a cell in Excel. I want to be able to extract just the second part of text (descriptions) in quotes. Is there any way to do this using Excel?

Like, instead of this:

1,1,"Pound","The foe is physically pounded with a long tail or a foreleg, etc.",0,40,0,100,35,0,0,0,115,0
2,2,"Karate Chop","The foe is attacked with a sharp chop. It has a high critical-hit ratio.",43,50,1,100,25,0,0,0,115,0

I want this:

The foe is physically pounded with a long tail or a foreleg, etc.
The foe is attacked with a sharp chop. It has a high critical-hit ratio.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Save it in a text file with a .csv extension and open it in Excel. That will give you each comma separated item in its own cell.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly.